# Deploy containerized lambda with layer using CDK

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, machine-learning, aws-lambda, aws-cdk

I'm working on an ML project that utilizes AWS Lambda for building models and generating predictions. Lambdas are written in python and use several ML libraries like *pandas, sklearn, numpy, and scikit-learn*.
These lambdas use shared code that packaged by Lambda's layer.
I use AWS CDK for project deployment. CDK code is written in TypeScript, don't ask why I mix Python and Typescript, it's not relevant in this situation.

The size of the package (lambda code + layer) exceeds the maximum allowed size of 250MB because of ML libraries.

After AWS announcement of containerized lambdas support, I decided to try it out to overcome the 250MB limit. However, I didn't find any good example that fit my situation, so I'm trying to build it myself.

The CDK code looks like this:

```
...
// Create a lambda layer from code
// Code is located in lambda-code/ml directory and it looks 
// like any Python package with main ML and DB connection functions
const mlLayer = new PythonLayerVersion(this, 'mlLayer', {
      entry: './lambda-code/ml/',
})
...
// Lambda function is specified like
const classifyTransactionLambda = new DockerImageFunction(this, 'classifyTransactionLambda', {      
      code: DockerImageCode.fromImageAsset('./lambda-code/classify'),      
      memorySize: 512,      
      layers: [mlLayer],
      tracing: Tracing.ACTIVE,
      environment: {
        BUCKET_NAME: mlModelsBucket.bucketName,
        ENV: env
      }
});
...
```

The structure of the code looks like this:

[image]

Dockerfile in *classify* lambda:

```
# Use the python lambda image from AWS ECR
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.7

COPY requirements.txt ./

RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

COPY index.py ./

CMD ["index.classify_transaction_handler"]
```

When I run *cdk deploy* I'm getting the following error:

> This lambda function uses a runtime that is incompatible with this layer (FROM_IMAGE is not in [python3.7])

Does anyone run into problem like this? Is this error mean that *mlLayer* version is not compatible with lambda *classifyTransactionLambda*?

Any help would be very appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this point

> Functions defined as container images do not support layers. When you build a container image, you can package your preferred runtimes and dependencies as a part of the image.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-layers.html

So I modified my build to copy all layer/library code to each lambda function before building an image.

Comment: Is this still a thing? I can't find in the documentation that is not possible but i do find this link https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/working-with-lambda-layers-and-extensions-in-container-images/